# ROS Answers SE migration: beginner robot

Tags: ros, robot, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like an affordable beginner's robot that can be used for learning and exploring ROS. The ones that are compatible with ROS mentioned on the ROS website, are a little out of my budget at the moment. Are there any cheaper alternatives?

A simple mobile platform would be sufficient to begin with and then I can add more components as my proficiency with ROS increases. I tried search for other similar questions on the site, but it turned up naught...

The iRobot create would not be an option because I am from outside the US.. unless, they changed the rules that allows foreigners to buy iRobot creates..

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28413/beginner-robot/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where are you located? You might be able to work off of a Roomba instead of a Create.

For example, I think that's what [Turtlebot EU](http://turtlebot.eu) does. (Though they're not accepting orders currently).

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-24**:
Im in Asia. Either way, a turtle bot is too expensive I feel. I would simply be happy with a mobile platform without any other sensors. Something with motors, wheels and a base that can be controlled using ROS...

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-02-24**:
If you use a serializer MCU and 2 gearmotors with encoders, wheels will cost you about $250. But you have to assemble it your self, Pirobot  (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pi-robot-ros-pkg) has ROS software to make work

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-25**:
By a "serializer MCU" you mean a microcontroller that has a serial port and can communicate serially with the main computer?

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-02-25**:
Yes but most use a USB port (http://www.roboticsconnection.com/p-16-serializer-robot-controller.aspx) With the above setup you will have a basic robot that can be controlled with ROS the built in motor driver has enough power to carry a small laptop

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-25**:
How about the arduino? Would I be able to do the same thing with arduino? Because, it is a lot cheaper and there is a "rosserial" stack with a "rosserial_arduino" package which enables communication between the arduino and ROS. Ofcourse, I will probably have to buy a separate motor driver...no probs

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-02-25**:
Yes here is a link (http://www.hessmer.org/blog/) my own robot is based on a lot of this code here is the link to my blog (http://escaliente-robotics.blogspot.com.au/) it's a holomonic rob0t and uses a arduino mega

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi @cassander.  The Serializer MCU is now called the Element and is sold by cmRobot at http://www.cmrobot.com/#!element-.net.